Using YamlDotNet for serialization, but preserve original values
I'm using YamlDotNet to indent yaml files, and it works fine. However, when I do this, the final result also shows some changes in the values ​​of some properties, such as:

day: "Friday"
hours: [7, 17]

is transformed into:

day: Friday
hours:
7
17

Some more examples:
day_of_week: "Wednesday" => day_of_week: Wednesday
logfiles.download_enable: 'on' => logfiles.download_enable: on
I just want to indent the file, preserving the original values ​​of the variables, as they are client files, I cannot change them.
                var serializer = new SerializerBuilder()
                    //.WithNamingConvention(NullNamingConvention.Instance)
                    .WithIndentedSequences()
                    //.IgnoreFields()
                    .WithEventEmitter(nextEmitter => new QuoteSurroundingEventEmitter(nextEmitter))
                    //.JsonCompatible()
                    //.WithDefaultScalarStyle(ScalarStyle.Literal)
                    //.WithoutTypeInspector(inspector => )
                    //.WithoutTagMapping(typeof(Array))
                    //.ConfigureDefaultValuesHandling(DefaultValuesHandling.Preserve)
                    .Build();

                return serializer.Serialize(yamlDictionary);

        public class QuoteSurroundingEventEmitter : ChainedEventEmitter
        {
            public QuoteSurroundingEventEmitter(IEventEmitter nextEmitter) : base(nextEmitter)
            { }

            public override void Emit(ScalarEventInfo eventInfo, IEmitter emitter)
            {
                eventInfo.Style = ScalarStyle.Plain;
                base.Emit(eventInfo, emitter);
            }
        }

